# How to add ".php" extension using ".htaccess" file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Need to Modify .htaccess file so that

`www.abc.com/uid?1pd47f4s4g28a3f`

Should get redirected to

`www.abc.com/uid.php?id=1pd47f4s4g28a3f`

I tried below Codes :

```
#short link
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %uid.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you want to check if filename(from uri).php is present on local filesystem then you need to redirect request to that specific file without rewriting url in browser, if this is the case please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?id=%{QUERY_STRING} [END]
```

NOTE: In above rules change from `END` to `L`  in case you have further more rules.